# Type hinting Python dataclasses subclass without redefining default value

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

When using keyword only dataclasses to define fields of a base class that are inherited by subclasses, how should the fields be type hinted in the subclasses to denote that the fields have a limited set of permissible values without re-assigning the default value?

Example (for illustrative purposes - not a real world example):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import auto, StrEnum
from typing import Literal

class Direction(StrEnum):
    DOWN = auto()
    LEFT = auto()
    UP = auto()
    RIGHT = auto()
    UNKNOWN = auto()

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Base:
    direction: Direction = Direction.UNKNOWN

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Horizontal(Base):
    direction: Literal[Direction.LEFT, Direction.RIGHT, Direction.UNKNOWN]

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Vertical(Base):
    direction: Literal[Direction.DOWN, Direction.UP, Direction.UNKNOWN] = Direction.UNKNOWN


print(Horizontal())
print(Vertical())
```

I appreciate that this is purely type hinting and not enforced at runtime.

The `Horizontal` class can be instantiated without error (surprisingly - given that `direction` is defined again within this subclass without a default value) but pylint reports the following "E1125: Missing mandatory keyword argument 'direction' in constructor call"
Setting the value of `direction` in `Vertical` defeats the point of the default in the base class.

Comment: Not type safe since `direction` can be reassigned

Comment: Can you provide further detail? The type isn't enforced at runtime or for re-assignment but the question is about type hinting...

Comment: Just don't repeat `dataclass` decorator: you don't change runtime behaviour, so it's not required and pleases `mypy` ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=ba40d88ae2f8288db345746eec205212))

Comment: @STerliakov without repeating the `dataclass` decorator, the `direction` defined in `Horizontal` becomes a class variable (without a value) and type hinting with mypy doesn't report problems when it should (you can assign `Direction.DOWN` to `Horizontal.direction`

Comment: @gratz yes, indeed it doesn't work, sorry. How about [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=2d1487daca3c8cf4c7c516b75b96ce07)?

Comment: @STerliakov that looks great - thanks!